# adapter API on top of leafletjs and google maps

Tags: google-maps, leaflet

Does there exist an adapter lib that provides a homomorphic mapping API that allows you to use google maps or leafletjs underneath it.

obviously both leaflet and google map APIs are huge, and I wouldn't expect that if such a lib existed, it would implement the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Oh glory, I have searched far and wide, and have found what I was looking for:

http://mapstraction.com/